# Argsort.argsort - What is it doing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is numpy giving this result:

```
x = numpy.array([-1,5,-2,0])

print x.argsort().argsort()
```

> [1,3,0,2]

Comment: It is the indices of the elements in the original list in sorted order

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Was there something unclear in that?

Comment: That is not even python 3....

Answer (score 2):

The `data.argsort().argsort()` can provide us with the ranks of the original array.

Let's take an example:

`data = np.array([0.9, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6])`

When we apply `argsort()` on data, it returns the indices that would sort the array in ascending order. So, the output is `array([2, 1, 3, 0])`

If we apply `argsort()` once again on this output, it returns the indices that would sort the array of indices. So the output is `array([3, 1, 0, 2])`.

This is the desired output that gives us the ranks of the elements in the original `data` array.

To be more specific,

```
3 is the rank of 0.9.
1 is the rank of 0.5.
0 is the rank of 0.3.
2 is the rank of 0.6.
```

I hope that helps! Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) function

> Returns the indices that would sort an array.

---

```
x = numpy.array([-1, 5, -2, 0])
print(x.argsort())  # [2 0 3 1]
```

To get a sorted array, you need to use the order `[2 0 3 1]`

```
index [ 2  0 3 1]
        |  | | |
        v  v v v
value  -2 -1 0 5  << is sorted
```

---

Calling `x.argsort().argsort()` is same as `numpy.array([2, 0, 3, 1]).argsort()`. It gives

```
index [1 3 0 2]
       | | | |
       v v v v
value  0 1 2 3  << is sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `x.argsort()` returns the indices in the order that will sort the array `x`. When you call `argsort` again on this result, what you get is the array of indices that will sort the previous array of indices:

```
x.argsort()
# array([2, 0, 3, 1])
x.argsort().argsort()
# array([1, 3, 0, 2])
# To sort the array x.argsort(), you start with index 1 which hold the value 0, and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

argsort() gives the indexes of sorted array.

fist argsort() result is: [2, 0, 3, 1]

second argsort() results [1, 3, 0, 2]

You can find details in NumPy documentation.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html